# How to validate specific arguments in a specific order

Tags: python, argparse

I would like to be able to validate arguments passed to a script, so that I could have the following options available to me:

```
test.py user info <user name>
test.py user create <user name> <last name> <first name> <email>
test.py user create batch <file name>
test.py user delete <user name>

test.py room info <room number>
test.py room create <room number> <room name>
test.py room delete <room number
```

I currently have a very fugly cascade of `if, elif, else`:

```
if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
    if (sys.argv[1]).lower() == "user":
        if len(sys.argv) >= 3:
            if (sys.argv[2]).lower() == "info":
                if len(sys.argv) >= 4:
                    username = sys.argv[3]

                    get_user_info(username)
                else:
                    print("username not specified")
```

and I'm not even going to bother adding the elif, and else statements.

I've read that using argparse is a better way to do this, but I'm just not seeing how to implement it the way that would meet my needs.

As it is right now, if someone executes just the `test.py` file itself, it prints out valid arguments. Then if they execute `test.py user` by itself, it gives them the next set of valid arguments, and so on and so on. Once getting to the , there's no validation of those.

Please help! And thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `argparse.sub_parser`: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

Comment: Is the `usage` just as ugly?  When designing a commandline parser think about how you'll instruct your users.  Also focus more on what the user wants, and less on getting it just right.

Comment: `if sys.argv[1:]:` is prettier than the `len(sys.argv)` test.

Comment: Don't try too hard to squeeze `argparse` into this mold.  It is best when handling a number of flagged `options` in any order, along with a limited number of required positionals.  Expecting a particular order, or interrelatedness between arguments is not its strength.

Comment: @hpaulj responses to your comments: 1) example usage was shown in my question. I'd like to keep that use, especially since once I get to where the user provides the data for user/room/etc creation, those (right now) need to be in a specific order. I demonstrated to a primary end user and they liked it. 2) that's debatable, and while I don't necessarily disagree, the cascading remains. 3) so given my desire to maintain some level of organization in the command input, sounds like argparse isn't the right tool for this task?

Comment: @hpaulj since you know your way around `argparse` what do you think of my solution? Could you please leave some feedback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use argparse with choices to limit the input for the first 2 strings.  The remaining strings are more variable, but the if tests can take advantage of commonalities.

```
import argparse

def lower(astr):
    return astr.lower()

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('first', type=lower, choices=['user', 'room'])
parser.add_argument('second', type=lower, choices=['info','create','delete'])
parser.add_argument('rest', nargs='+')
parser.set_defaults(file=[], user=[], room=[])  # defaults

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)

# partial parse of the `rest` list of strings:

if args.first in ['user']:
    if args.second in ['create']:
         if args.rest[0] in ['batch']:
             args.files=args.rest[1:]
         else:
              args.user = args.rest
    else:
        args.user = args.rest[0]
else:
    args.room = args.rest
args.rest=[]    
print(args)
```

the help:

```
1553:~/mypy$ python stack50071515.py -h
usage: stack50071515.py [-h] {user,room} {info,create,delete} rest [rest ...]

positional arguments:
  {user,room}
  {info,create,delete}
  rest

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
```

test inputs:

```
1545:~/mypy$ python stack50071515.py user info name
Namespace(file=[], first='user', rest=['name'], room=[], second='info', user=[])
Namespace(file=[], first='user', rest=[], room=[], second='info', user='name')

1549:~/mypy$ python stack50071515.py user create a b c
Namespace(file=[], first='user', rest=['a', 'b', 'c'], room=[], second='create', user=[])
Namespace(file=[], first='user', rest=[], room=[], second='create', user=['a', 'b', 'c'])

1549:~/mypy$ python stack50071515.py user create batch file
Namespace(file=[], first='user', rest=['batch', 'file'], room=[], second='create', user=[])
Namespace(file=[], files=['file'], first='user', rest=[], room=[], second='create', user=[])

1550:~/mypy$ python stack50071515.py user delete name
Namespace(file=[], first='user', rest=['name'], room=[], second='delete', user=[])
Namespace(file=[], first='user', rest=[], room=[], second='delete', user='name')

1550:~/mypy$ python stack50071515.py room info number
Namespace(file=[], first='room', rest=['number'], room=[], second='info', user=[])
Namespace(file=[], first='room', rest=[], room=['number'], second='info', user=[])

1550:~/mypy$ python stack50071515.py room create a b
Namespace(file=[], first='room', rest=['a', 'b'], room=[], second='create', user=[])
Namespace(file=[], first='room', rest=[], room=['a', 'b'], second='create', user=[])

1550:~/mypy$ python stack50071515.py room delete 23
Namespace(file=[], first='room', rest=['23'], room=[], second='delete', user=[])
Namespace(file=[], first='room', rest=[], room=['23'], second='delete', user=[])
```

Comment: Finally got around to digging through these. Marking this as the answer because it seems closer to what I want. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using **argparse**. It is inspired by the way _catkin_tools_ does it.

### Approach

1. Use `parse_config` dictionary of dictionary to create entries for `<category> <verb>` like `user info`.
2. The `parse_config` for `user info` can be found in `parse_config['user']['info']` and contains fields `desc(ription)`, `main`, and `prepare_parser`.
3. `main` is a callable object (i.e. a function) which is called in the last line of the script like this: `sys.exit(args.main(args))`. Ignore the `sys.exit(..)` for this. `args.main` is the function which after parsing the arguments given from the command line will point to the right entry point depending on the arguments given. How this works is by using `subparser.set_defaults(main=main_for_this_subparser)`. This means that if this specific subparser gets activated, then `args.main` points to `main_for_this_subparser` which can be any function.
4. `prepare_parser` is also a function, which can be customized for each command to add more arguments. Since *user* always requires as first argument a `<user name>`, I've used a `def parser_user_default(parser): parser.add_argument('user_name')` for all three verbs (*info*, *create*, *delete*). Since *create* needs more arguments, this gets a special `parser_user_create` function where first `parser_user_default` gets called but then more arguments are added.

#### Further reading

- The [documentation of set_defaults](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.set_defaults) is helpful:

  > Parser-level defaults can be particularly useful when working with multiple parsers. See the add_subparsers() method for an example of this type.
- Catkin-Tools code is quite helpful (and clever):

  - `setup.py`: https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/blob/master/setup.py
  - Main entry point with all the argument preparation: https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/blob/master/catkin_tools/commands/catkin.py
  - Example `prepare_parser`/`prepare_arguments` for `catkin build`: https://github.com/catkin/catkin_tools/blob/master/catkin_tools/verbs/catkin_build/cli.py#L95

#### Further Notes

My solution so far does not handle calling `test.py user create batch <batch file>`. For one, I do not think this is actually a good CLI because a user may never be called "batch". Maybe usage as `user create --batch <file>` would be better. On the other hand, this I couldn't get to work directly with argparse. If you do experiment with this, consider `parse_known_args()` which lets you mix argparse with manual argument handling.

I'm not completely happy with my implementation. In hindsight, a recursive implementation, which would handle nested dictionaries to any level, would be cleaner. Currently, the implementation handles exactly `<category> <verb>`.

### Complete Code

```
"""
test.py user info <user name>
test.py user create <user name> <last name> <first name> <email>
test.py user create batch <file name>
test.py user delete <user name>

test.py room info <room number>
test.py room create <room number> <room name>
test.py room delete <room number
"""

from argparse import ArgumentParser
import sys


def main_user_info(args):
    print('You called "user info" for user {}'.format(args.user_name))

def main_user_create(args):
    print('You called "user create" for : {u}, {last} {first} {mail}'.format(u=args.user_name,
                                                                             last=args.last_name,
                                                                             first=args.first_name,
                                                                             mail=args.email))
def main_user_create_batch(args):
    print('User batch creation using file {}'.format(args.filename))

def main_user_delete(args):
    pass

def main_room_info(args):
    print('Room info called for room number {}'.format(args.room_number))

def main_room_create(args):
    print('Creating room number {nr} with name {name}'.format(nr=args.room_number,
                                                              name=args.room_name))

def main_room_delete(args):
    pass

def parser_user_default(parser):
    parser.add_argument('user_name', metavar='<user name>')
    return parser

def parser_user_create(parser):
    parser = parser_user_default(parser)  # argument <user name>
    parser.add_argument('last_name', metavar='<last name>')
    parser.add_argument('first_name', metavar='<first name>')
    parser.add_argument('email', metavar='<email>')
    return parser

def parser_room_default(parser):
    parser.add_argument('room_number', metavar='<room number>')
    # Above: restrict room number to ints: 'type=int'
    # Restrict room number to known rooms: 'choices=list_of_known_rooms'
    # Restrict room numbers to 1 to 1000: 'choices=range(1, 1001)'
    return parser

def parser_room_create(parser):
    parser = parser_room_default(parser)
    parser.add_argument('room_name', metavar='<room name>')
    return parser

parse_config = {
    'user': {'info': {'desc': 'Show user info', 'main': main_user_info,
                      'prepare_parser': parser_user_default},
             'create': {'desc': 'Create new user', 'main': main_user_create,
                        'prepare_parser': parser_user_create},
             'delete': {'desc': 'Delete user', 'main': main_user_delete,
                        'prepare_parser': parser_user_default}
             },
    'room': {'info': {'desc': 'Show room info', 'main': main_room_info,
                      'prepare_parser': parser_room_default},
             'create': {'desc': 'Show room info', 'main': main_room_create,
                      'prepare_parser': parser_room_create},
             'delete': {'desc': 'Delete a room', 'main': main_room_delete,
                      'prepare_parser': parser_room_default}
             },
}


def prepare_verb_args(parser, category):
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title='verb')

    for verb, config in parse_config[category].items():
        subparser = subparsers.add_parser(verb, description=config['desc'])
        subparser = config['prepare_parser'](subparser)

        # Reading 'set_defaults' is helpful. Notably, this overwrites default of args.main
        # when given this particular category on command line.
        subparser.set_defaults(main=config['main'])
    return parser

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.set_defaults(main=lambda _: parser.print_usage())

    # Inspired by 'catkin_tools'.
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest='category', title='category')

    for c in parse_config.keys():
        subparser = subparsers.add_parser(c, description='Act on {}'.format(c))
        subparser = prepare_verb_args(subparser, category=c)
        # NOTE: Somehow the lambda binds to the last 'subparser' in the loop.
        # This is a bug but I haven't got the time to fix it.
        subparser.set_defaults(main=lambda x: subparser.print_usage())

    args = parser.parse_args()
    sys.exit(args.main(args))
```